# Conditionally use WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just see this:

```
SELECT clientid,clientname,startdate,enddate,age FROM clients 
WHERE clientid IN (1,2,3,4,5)
AND CASE WHEN age>10 THEN enddate>'31-05-2013'
END
```

My question: I want the second condition ***enddate>'31-05-2013'*** only if **age > 10**

What's wrong in this query?

Comment: It's usually good practice to write string literals that will be converted to dates in unambiguous formats - it'll help prevent working scripts from breaking if you ever work on a server with different default settings. `'20130531'` (e.g. `YYYYMMDD` with no separators) would be an unambiguous version of the above.

Comment: @Downvoter: What't the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select clientid,clientname,startdate,enddate,age from clients 
where clientid in (1,2,3,4,5)
and (age <= 10 OR enddate > '31-05-2013')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use a case expression like this. Try this instead:

```
Select clientid,clientname,startdate,enddate,age from clients 
where clientid in (1,2,3,4,5)
and (age<=10 or enddate>'31-05-2013')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that could be wrong.  One is that dates are normally in `2013-05-31` order.  That might change depending on locale settings; let us assume so.

Otherwise, you need to write the query more simply as:

```
SELECT clientid, clientname, startdate, enddate, age
  FROM clients 
 WHERE clientid IN (1,2,3,4,5)
   AND ((age > 10 AND enddate > '31-05-2013') OR (age <= 10))
```

Or, using the case:

```
SELECT clientid, clientname, startdate, enddate, age
  FROM clients 
 WHERE clientid IN (1,2,3,4,5)
   AND CASE 
       WHEN age > 10 THEN enddate > '31-05-2013'
       ELSE TRUE
       END
```

(The default for no ELSE clause is NULL.)

Comment: Since when does SQL have a boolean data type that can be used like this?

Comment: @Lucero: is your question about SQL-Server or the language SQL? Or the average SQL-product out there?

Comment: @ypercube, all of the ones you mentionned. Unless I completely missed something, neither SQL Server nor any other SQL product I know allows this second type of query (e.g. using a predicate as expression, and vice-versa).

Comment: @Lucero: See the [SQL-Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/13394/1) It works in MySQL and Postgres (but not in SQL-Server)

Comment: @ypercube, I see (and thanks for the link to SQL Fiddle - didn't know that tool!). Oracle, SQLite, SQL Server don't support it, which are the ones I use... it certainly isn't part of the SQL standard as far as I can tell. Since this question is tagged `sql-server`, I still think that those aren't valid answers here.

Comment: @Lucero: To be honest, I'm not sure about the standard, you are most probably right. And SQL-Fiddle is great tool, yeah! (created by [@Jake Feasel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel))

Comment: The SQL Standard has had BOOLEAN since SQL-99 (it wasn't in SQL-92).  Whether it can be used in the CASE formulation is more questionable; indeed, I do not recommend the CASE and prefer the simple OR condition, assuming that I've interpreted the required condition correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select clientid,clientname,startdate,enddate,age from clients
where clientid in (1,2,3,4,5)
and  ( (age>10 and enddate>'31-05-2013') or (age<=10 and enddate<='31-05-2013') )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use unambigious dateformat

```
Select clientid,clientname,startdate,enddate,age from clients  
where clientid in (1,2,3,4,5) 
and (age <= 10 OR enddate > '20130531')
```

See this for reason http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10899/understanding-datetime-column-part-ii.aspx